# How to make highlighted region to appear above the sidebars

Tags: theming

I am creating a sub theme from Zen Starter Kit. How do i Enable the highlighted region to appear above the sidebars. I want to place a slide show there. I am able to do so but then when i place content into my sidebars they appear below the slide show...Please help..what changes or additions to i need to do in my theme files and where and which files

Comment: Why don't you attach some screen shots...may be that will help people understand your problem better.

Comment: whether u need to add a region in sidebar area or u need to assign some block into sidebar region?

Comment: thank you all...i figured it..i added a new region and rendered it in page.tpl.php